# Android: Remove Enter Key from softkeyboard

Tags: android, return, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, enter

In my login form when user clicks on an EditText and presses the enter key, this inserts a new line, therefore increasing the EditText's size. Next moment, it returns to its previous place and prints a dot in the password field (which is the next field).

I want to remove this enter key from the softkeyboard. Is it possible?

Comment: I think the easiest way is to android:inputType="textPersonName" it will stop from entering in a textView..

Comment: `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` removes the Return Key from the SoftKeyboard.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I am afraid you can't do this. But one thing is you can handle the softkeyboard keyevents like this,

```
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {


                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                        && event.getKeyCode() ==       KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    Log.i("event", "captured");

                    return false;
                } 
                else if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                        && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
                    Log.i("Back event Trigered","Back event");

                }

            }

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Apart from this, you have to note that providing the attribute `android:singleLine=true` will make your edittext from growing in size when the soft keyborad ENTER is pressed

Comment: "android:singleLine=true" saved me :D Try that one. And thanks for answer @Andro .

Answer (score 37):

Use :
`android:singleLine = "true"`
or
     `edittext.setSingleLine();`

And your ENTER key is gone

Answer (score 24):

add this tag to textView in xml

```
    android:singleLine = "true"
```

Comment: android:maxLines = "1" & android:lines = "1" didnt really work..
but android:singleLine = "true" worked..
[Developer.Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:singleLine) does not say android:singleLine is deprecated!!

Answer (score 4):

Inside the tag `EditText` you only have to do:

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

this remove the enter key in the keyboard

***UPDATE***

Inasmuch as `android:singleLine="true"` **is deprecated** I use `android:maxLines="1"` to avoid the enter in a `EditText`. How the name of the method says only ***N*** lines is permitted.

Comment: it's deprecated now

Answer (score 0):

New update :

android:maxLines="1"

Answer (score 0):

If you want something more generic in your .java:

`boolean state = true;
yourTextInputEditText.setSingleLine(state);`