# Edittext Android Multiple Lines

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have the following issue.
I have an edit text where the user puts in the movie name. If the user presses enter I want the focus to go to the next edittext, where the user types the description of the movie.
I do not want the user to be able to put a movie title with two lines, ie I want it all on one line without enter.
However when I use android:singleLine="true", or android:maxLines, the movie title is printed on one line, but if the movie title is long it will not be all displayed at once (have to scroll across).
I want the edittext to grow in height to numerous lines if necessary, but I don't want the user to use enter to make new lines.
How do I do this.
Here is my code:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Movie title"
    android:textSize="15sp"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:id="@+id/et_AddMovieTitle"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Movie description"
    android:textSize="15sp"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:id="@+id/et_AddMovieDescription"

    />
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe and idea would be to create your custom `editText`, you could override the `onKeyDown` method and check if the user has pressed enter, if so you could hide the keyboard or something.

```
class CustomEditTexxt extends EditText
{
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) 
        {
            // hide the keyboard
            return true;
        }
        // handle all other keys in the default way
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked well for me, however a interesting thing happened. Even though the enter key on my keyboard was disabled, but on the emulator on the virtual keyboard the enter button still returned a new line. Why is this? Would it work on a device (not an emulator)?

Answer (score 1):

use

android:inputType="textMultiline"

& remove

android:imeOptions="actionDone"

Answer (score 0):

try it.
Add input type in the edit text.

> for Single line

```
android:inputType="text"
```

> for multiline

```
android:inputType="textMultiline"
```

Comment: Tried this. Doesn't work. Just scolls along and doesn't display it all at once. TextMultiline, allows the user to press enter and go to a new line. I don't want that

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to override the enter key functionality in order to prevent the user from using "Enter" to add a line in an EditText. You should be able to simply change the focus to the next EditText here and override the new line logic.

I think this post might be of value to you. 
[Handling "Enter" key in an EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489852/android-handle-enter-in-an-edittext)

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've used the `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` to force the user to the next input field.

You can check the [action](http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html#Action) docs to verify [imeOptions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions) is what you need. You may also want to take a look at using the `actionDone` option for easily submitting the form when the last field is selected.

So a quick/cheap way is to setup as a single-lined `EditText` with enabled "Next" button:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:id="@+id/et_AddMovieTitle"
    />
```

And then force the `EditText` to do [soft-wrapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13563946/1258450), by applying the following programmatic configuration:

```
editText.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
editText.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

This worked for me testing on android 5.1, but is not really conducive for re-use. So if your needs are more demanding, you can also consider [subclassing `EditText`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5037488/1258450)

Comment: To make sure I understand your problem, you want to:
(1) override the "enter" key to move the user to the next available input, 
(2) don't allow the user to create a new line within the `EditText`, 
(3) format the `EditText` to properly wrap lines when applicable?

Comment: Correct, this takes me to the next editview and the user cannot press enter. However I still have the problem that the edittext remains on one line, and cannot be viewed all at the same time without scrolling across.

Comment: Edited answer after doing some more research and validating locally. It's definitely a hack, though...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, and setting only `textMultiLine` will not work, add `android:scrollbars="vertical"` and you want to define a `android:maxHeight="max_size_in_dp"` if it overflow the size user must scroll.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enviar seu comentário"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:maxHeight="100dp"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"/>
```

`editText.setText("big_text_description_here");`

The text will be displayed as you want.

Comment: I do not want the user to be able to press the enter button. Does you picture show this?

Comment: @RBerman The image was a little confusing, i edited my answer, try it now and let me know if it help you.

Comment: The user can still press the enter button to get to a new line.

Comment: @RBerman You can't disable or remove this buttom from keyboard check this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10564062/1879661) , until you `disable it programatically` for do that, check this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6991402/1879661) and combine it with my answer.